# Single tab with multiple fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have an app in which I have three tabs on the `ActionBar` and and each tab has a `Fragment` associated with it in the `ViewPager` such that the user of the app can scroll between the different tabs/fragmens using a swipe gesture. So there are 3 tabs and 3 fragments and there is a one to one relation between them.

What I want to achieve is that inside each tab there should be 3 fragments and user should be able to navigate between them using the swipe gesture. Similarly other tabs can also contain different number of fragments and user should be able to navigate between them. So in this case there are three tabs and those can have "n" number of fragment such that there is one to many relationship.

How can I achieve such a behavior using or do I have to change my current approach and do something else. Kindly provide me a path here, I am stuck on this for quite a sometime.

Comment: This will be highly counter intuitive for the user and you should rethink your approach.

Comment: Yes I agree, but still I want to know how can I achieve this.

Comment: **If** the sub tabs will fill the entire `ViewPager` then you can simply put all the fragments in the `ViewPager` and only change the tab when a proper calculated position is reached. The same with the `ViewPager`'s listener.

Comment: How can I put all the fragments in the `ViewPager`, can you give some sample code ?